# Object value update inside loop added values to the list instead of updating list

Tags: java, list, object, arraylist, static-methods

I want to update my matrixlist from main method .In my main method I have created object to update my matrixlist.
I want to update my matrix list after carrying some operations inside loop in main method.
So with this intend I updated my object inside loop in main method.

This is what my MatrixList Looks like:-

```
public class MatrixList {

    private static double N1;

    ..................
        ...........
            ...............

    private static double N4;


    private static List<Double> IN1= new ArrayList<>();

   .....................
    ....................
        ....................

    private static List<Double> IN4 = new ArrayList<>();



    public static void setIN1(double N1) {
        MatrixList.N1=N1;
        IN1.add( MatrixList.N1);
    }

     ...............
    .......................
            .....................

    public static void setIN4(double N4) {
         MatrixList.N4=N4;
        IN4.add( MatrixList.N4);
    }                       


    public static List<Double> getIN1() {
        return MatrixList.N1;
    }

    ....................
    .....................
        .................


    public static List<Double> getIN4() {
        return MatrixList.N4;
    }

    }
}
```

This is What My Main Method Looks Like:-

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        ReadCSV readcsv = new ReadCSV();
        readcsv.ReadCSV();


        MatrixSerialInitialize init = new MatrixSerialInitialize();
        init.matrix_initialize();     


        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {

        init.matrix_initialize();
    }

        int i=0;
    for(Double d:MatrixList.getIN4())
    {
    System.out.println(d);
    System.out.println("i,"+i);
    i++;
        }      

      }
```

This is how I initialized my Matrix:-

```
public class MatrixSerialInitialize {
   public void matrix_initialize()
   {
       double j=-0.8164; 

       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {


            while(j==0)
            {
             j+=0.051025;   
            }

            MatrixList.setIN1(j);
            j+=0.051025;

            while(j==0)
            {
             j+=0.051025;   
            }

          ..................
          ..................

            MatrixList.setIN4(j);
            j+=0.051025;
        }                   

   }


}
```

But after updating my objects inside loop what I encounterd was my list was updated three times.This is not my intend.I want to update previous values in list.

Is it because of static list or is there any way I can update list inside loop?

Can Someone help me out with this?

Comment: What loop are you talking about exactly? There are several in your code. What output do you expect and what output do you actually see? Is there an issue with j == 0 never being true due to rounding? As it stands it's very difficult to read the code due to the unnecessary loops, uneven indentation, non - standard naming convention, double artithmetic etc so it's hard to help.

Comment: @matt helliwell The loop I am talking about is the one I am using in main method.............I wanted to replace my existing array list by running the object in loop............bt I came to know that arraylist is not applicable for this purpose as it just adds and do not replace............even though I use set(); in arraylist.